# Add multiple log4net appenders

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net, appender

I'm currently trying to add a Microsoft Teaqms appender to my log4net file. In this file I already have different appenders. My current try looks like this:

```
<log4net debug="true">
    <root>
        <level value="WARN" />
        <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="myMicrosoftTeamsAppender" />
    </root>
    <logger name="ErpLogger" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="ChangeHistoryLogger" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender"/>
    </logger>
    <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
        <bufferSize value="1" />
        <ReconnectOnError value="true" />
        <connectionType
          value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <connectionStringName value="LogConnection" />
        <commandText
          value="INSERT INTO log4netlog ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" /> 
    </appender>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender">
        <threshold value="ALL" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender> 
    <appender name="myMicrosoftTeamsAppender" type="log4net.MicrosoftTeams.MicrosoftTeamsAppender, log4net.MicrosoftTeams">
        <WebhookUrl value="my Teams URL" />     
        <titleLayout>
            <conversionPattern value="Title - %p: %date [%c]" />
        </titleLayout>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%-5level %logger - %message" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
</log4net>
```

So I already had an test project with this Teams appender and everytime I added a Log a message in the Teams channel gets created. But now I'm trying to add this in my real project and it doesn't work. I tried it with this code in my Startup class:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
var logger = LogManager.GetLogger("myMicrosoftTeamsAppender");
logger.Info("Info.");
logger.Fatal("Fatal!", new ArgumentException("42"));
```

How can I solve this?
let me know if you need any other parts of the code :)

Edit:
I found this in the Output:

```
...
log4net: Loading Appender [teams] type: [log4net.MicrosoftTeams.MicrosoftTeamsAppender, log4net.MicrosoftTeams]
log4net:ERROR Could not create Appender [teams] of type [log4net.MicrosoftTeams.MicrosoftTeamsAppender, log4net.MicrosoftTeams]. Reported error follows.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Die Datei oder Assembly "log4net.MicrosoftTeams" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
Dateiname: "log4net.MicrosoftTeams"
   bei System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   bei System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
   bei System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   bei System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   bei log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetTypeFromString(Assembly relativeAssembly, String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   bei log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetTypeFromString(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   bei log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ParseAppender(XmlElement appenderElement)

...
```

Update:
I'm just getting this error now:

```
log4net:ERROR Appender named [myMicrosoftTeamsAppender] not found.
```

[Additonal informations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71309025/log4net-error-appender-named-not-found)

Comment: add `<nlog throwConfigExceptions="true" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.txt" ` this will create internal log of nlog and hopefully will point you to the error.

Comment: Does https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#appender-assembly help?

Comment: @sgmoore no tot really. I think the problem is that the MicrosoftteamsAppender can't get loaded and I don't know how I can fix that, I've tried many different things but I'm always getting this error. But thanks

Comment: Try loading the log4net.MicrosoftTeams.dll manually before any of your log4net code. If the problem was log4net could not find the appender, this may fix your problem. If there is some other reason why the dll can not be loaded, then the exception or inner exception or LoaderException should tell you why.

Comment: @sgmoore How exactly can I do this? I'm using for this the log4net.MicrosoftTeams Nuget. Shouldn't it work automatically when the Nuget is installed?

Comment: If you have a reference, then try `new log4net.MicrosoftTeams.MicrosoftTeamsAppender();`

Comment: @sgmoore no, I don't have a reference